# Complex function with real image

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f:C \subset \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function and $C$ a connected subset. I want to prove that if $f(z)$ is real for all $z \in C$, then $f$ is constant.

Write $f$ as a power series $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_n (z-a)^n$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in C$.

Since $f(z)$ is real, the imaginary part of the power series is null. I want to know if I can conclude that $a_n=0$ for all $n \geq 1$, for, if $a_1=0$, then $f'(a)=0$ for all $a$ in $C$ and by connectedness, $f$ is constant. (Or, $f(z)=a_0=f(a)\Rightarrow f $ is constant)

Comment: I forgot to say, I can't use Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: What can we use? Can we use all that comes from the power series? From the power series we have Cauchy formula, Maximum modulus theorem, Rouche theorem, Open mapping theorem. Of course, Cauchy-Riemann equations but those are vetted. From the Open mapping theorem it follows directly.

Comment: We can only use that if $f'(z)=0$ for all $z \in C$, where $C$ is connected, then $f$ is constant and that $f$ can be written as a power sum. (Precisely, the chapter 3, section 2 of Conway's book, but Cauchy-Riemann equations)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use the CR equations for the proof the use of power series is even more tabu. But it is sufficient to work with the definition of complex differentiability.

Consider a point $z\in{\rm dom}(f)$ and assume that $f'(z)=:A\ne0$. There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$\left|{f(z+h)-f(z)\over h}-A\right|<{|A|\over2}\qquad\bigl(|h|<\epsilon\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that 
$$|f(z+h)-f(z)-Ah|<{|A h|\over2}\qquad\bigl(0<|h|<\epsilon\bigr)$$
or
$$f(z+h)-f(z)=Ah\left(1+{\Theta_h\over2}\right)\qquad\bigl(0<|h|<\epsilon\bigr)\tag{1}$$
for some complex $\Theta_h$ of absolute value $\leq1$. Now choose $$h:=t i\bar A$$ with $t>0$ small enough. Then the left hand side of $(1)$ is real by assumption, but the right hand side is definitively not real.

From this we conclude that in fact $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in{\rm dom}(f)$. This immediately implies that all partial derivatives of $u$, $v$ are $\equiv0$; and as a consequence  $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (that doesn't require a power series representation) is to mimic the proof you'd use to deduce the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Namely, write $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ with $u$ and $v$ real-valued. By hypothesis, $v \equiv 0$, and the complex limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}
$$
exists. Let $h$ approach $0$ along the real axis, then along the imaginary axis, expressing the results in terms of partials of $u$. The fact that these limits are equal tells you something about $u$....